# DataGridCell Binded value update upon row selection change

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

My propblem is that DataGrid sends new value set by user with GUI only when the selected line is changed. When I modify value in form and press "Enter" to confirm input, everything works fine (because "Enter" moves selection to next line). But when I modify value in cell and press with mouse to any other cell in current row, new value is assigned to cell but not sent to binded object. In debugger I see that converter's ConvertBack method is called but Field.Value property setter  is not! Field.Value property setter breakpoint fires only after row selection change. How can I force my Model object value change after cell edit finish, not row selection changed?

DataGrid's style:

```
<Style x:Key="ElementDataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="Cell"/>
    <Setter Property="CellStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">               
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                    </Trigger>                  
                </Style.Triggers>
                <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ElementDataGridStyleCellStyle_Loaded"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>   
</Style>
```

Code that binds DataGrid to my Model

```
private void SetDataGridContent(DataGrid grid, Core.Item.ItemCollection collection)
{
    grid.Columns.Clear();            
    if (collection != null)
    {                       
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.FieldProps.Count; i++)
        {
            Core.FieldProp prop = collection.FieldProps[i];
            if (prop.VisualName != null)
            {               
                MultiBinding multiBinding = new MultiBinding()
                {
                    Converter = new Visual.FieldValueConverter()
                };
                multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding($"Fields[{i}]"));
                multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding($"Fields[{i}].Value"));
                DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn
                {
                    Binding = multiBinding,
                    Header = prop.VisualName,
                    IsReadOnly = !prop.UIEditable,                            
                };              
                SetColumnFieldIndex(column, i);                             
                grid.Columns.Add(column);                        
            }                    
        }       
    }
    grid.ItemsSource = collection;            
}
```

Fields - is ObservableCollection successor

```
sealed class FieldCollection : ObservableCollection<Field>
```

Field class implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface

```
public class Field : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _value;

    public string Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value != value)
            {
                Modify(value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Modify(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Value converter looks like this:

```
class FieldValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object[] result = new object[2];
        result[0] = Binding.DoNothing; //DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        result[1] = value;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why are you not using xaml to define your DataGrid bindings? It's not really standard to setup a DataGrid in some code-behind method or even at ViewModel level.

Comment: @rejy11 
1. Fields is collection of variable size. 
2. Not all Fields should be displayed (condition "if (prop.VisualName != null)").
3. This code is a bit simplified. In my project I also create different types of DataGribColumn, depending on type of content
If you know how to do it in xaml please tell me.

Anyway I don't think that it matters where I do binding in xaml or code behind, or am I wrong?

Comment: As far as I know you can accomplish everything you want to do in code behind but one of the main selling points of WPF is the ability to use XAML. You're much more likely to get help from the community on your question by using XAML as not many people use code behind to construct their views.

Comment: You can use custom DataGridColumns also, just create a class inheriting from DataGridColumn and then create a XAML namespace reference at the top of the view and then use your CustomDataGridColumn e.g. `<customControls:CustomDataGridColumn />`

Comment: @rejy11 If you have an example of how to accomplish with XAML what is done now in code behind, please provide it. I have more than 200 sucessors of Core.Item class which data should be displayed in datagrid (with variable number of columns). I have no desire to make 200 fixed datagrids markup in xaml. Maybe I'm missing something... Nevertheless, this all is offtop.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. If you mean that your DataGrid must be showing 200 Items then all you need to do is set the `ItemsSource` property of the DataGrid which will be a binding to some backing property collection. I suggest reading some WPF MVVM tutorials or even having a look on YouTube - it seems you're over complicating things here.

Comment: Moving everything to xaml changed nothing. Value of binded property is updated only after selecting cell in different line.